# Having trouble figuring out what this code does

Tags: python, function

I'm new to Python, so there might be some good reason for this, but it looks like it does nothing:

```
def preprocess(t):
    return t
```

It looks to me like one of the old time-wasting functions to slow something down.

I see "preprocess" show up in several spots downstream, so if it's calling "preprocess" and passing to "t", then returning "t", I have no idea why it's passing it back-and-forth.

Comment: It's probably meant as a no-op for something that requires a callback, but no actual preprocessing is needed.

Comment: Maybe it's a place-holder. If someone wants to "preprocess" the argument, they can change the function and its effect will happen everywhere it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this code does nothing useful.

It is likely being used as a placeholder implementation so that the code calling this function can run; even if `preprocess` isn't implemented yet.

The alternative would be to comment out or otherwise remove the calls to `preprocess` until it's implemented, but that could be awkward if it's used in multiple places.

Comment: @BitTwiddler I'll note, I agree with Chepner that `identity` functions are useful; I use them quite often. From the name though, I don't believe that that was the intent of this code. That's why I say that it *does* nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

The identity function is useful as a no-op in places where some function is otherwise expected. For example, you can eliminate a conditional from a function like

```
def do_something(value, f=None):
    if f is not None:
        value = f(value)
    # some some more stuff with value
```

by writing

```
def do_something(value, f=preprocess):
    value = f(value)
    # do some more stuff with value
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a default do nothing implementation in a base class that is expected to be extended and the behavior updated in the child class.   Would need more context around the function to tell if that is the case.